# Is there a way of executing functions in the order of an array

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting

I have an array containing a few values. Each value correlates to a function that needs to be executed. The order of the array can change, but it will always contain the same set of elements.

Example:

```
function a{ echo 'a'; }
function b{ echo 'b'; }
function c{ echo 'c'; }
...

$order = array("b", "c", "a", ...);

//This would return bca
```

This entire process would need to be done 3 times on a every page load with a different order each time. I've tried doing it with a switch inside a foreach, but that is very slow.

Example:

```
foreach($order as $item){
  switch ($item) {
    case: 'a':
      a();
      break;
    case: 'b':
      b();
      break;
    case: 'c':
      c();
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a good efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: That foreach/switch construct itself can hardly be what’s slowing this down.

Comment: You can implement the `arrap_map` function, example

    array_map(function($v){
      return $v();
    }, $order);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler way is:

```
foreach($order as $item){ $item(); }
```

Fiddle https://3v4l.org/dJ9l9